# How to find estimated standard error of $ \widehat{θ} = T(\widehat{F}_n) = \widehat{F}_n(b) - \widehat{F}_n(a)$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

[image]

Here, $T(F)$ is statistical functional of F such that $T(F) = F(b) - F(a)$ for 
fixed number $a$ and $b$. We have a ECDF $\widehat{F}_n$ for $X_1, ....X_n$ from distribution $F$. 
Our task is to find $Var(\widehat{θ})$ where $ \widehat{θ} = T(\widehat{F}_n) = \widehat{F}_n(b) - \widehat{F}_n(a)$.

Comment: Please edit the post to share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I got it how to find confidence interval by applying 'A Nonparametric Confidence Band for F' which is built by DKW inequality. But it is not clear how to estimate the standard error of $\widehat{θ}$ so it would be perfect if I received a good solution? @StubbornAtom

Comment: Find variance of $\hat\theta$ first of all, for which you can use that $n\hat F$ has a binomial distribution.

Comment: Please, could you make it clear what do you mean? @StubbornAtom

Comment: I would ask you again to add some context to the post, highlighting exactly where you are having trouble.

Comment: I have done what you've asked to me. @StubbornAtom

Comment: I've got it. Thank you! @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 0):

First check whether 
$$
\mathbb E\hat\theta=\theta 
$$
Use the definition of empirical distribution function
$$
\mathbb E[\hat F(t)]=\mathbb E\left[\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\leq t\}}\right]
$$
and the linearity property of expectation.

For calculating variance check and use the identity 
$$
\mathbb 1_{\{X_i\,\leq\, b\}} - \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\,\leq\, a\}} = \mathbb 1_{\{a\,<\,X_i\,\leq \,b\}} \quad \text{for} \quad a<b.
$$
and variance properties: $\mathop{\text{Var}}(cX)=c^2\mathop{\text{Var}}(X)$. 
$$
\mathop{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta) = \mathop{\text{Var}}\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\leq b\}}-\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\leq a\}}\right) = \frac1{n^2}\mathop{\text{Var}}\,\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{a<X_i\leq b\}} \right). 
$$
Find the distribution of a sum in brackets and its variance.